# How to send information to users on Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android

assume I have an Android app written in Xamarin. Is there a way for me (i.e. the developer who publish that app on the Play Store) to interact with the users of my app by sending some information that is automatically stored in a local DB? 
In particular, I want to send the users a new code that will change the behaviour of the app based on some previously coded logic. 
For example, assume the app when loaded reads a table on a SQLite DB and looks at the most recent record. Say that when the app is installed and launched the first time, the first record has a value equal to 1. 
The app reads that table every time the app is launched and based on the most recent record some behaviour of the app changes. 
For example, at start (i.e. when the most recent record is equal to 1) the background color of my main activity is white. Then I send a new code to the users and say that the new record added to that DB table is 2. 
The app now reads that record and changes the background color to green (because, when designed, the app has some switch case that changes the background color based on a given value, i.e 1=white, 2=green, etc.).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

First, when starting the application, you send a request to the server to synchronize your local database, so you will get always the latest values.

After that, you can load the views according to the information that you have, and apply your logic.

Comment: Glad to hear that is possible. But what do you mean by sending request to server to synchronize the DB?

Comment: You send a request to your API / server, to get the value you want. And then, you insert it into the local database.

Comment: But can you point me to some resource explaining how this can be easily setup?